# text.splice(); array item deleted and saved when reloading sketch

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help.
I'm trying make it so that when I use `text.splice()` it keeps the changes when i reload the page.
Here is what I'm trying to do. It will Delete the item of the array that I wrote in the input element, but its not saving the changes made with `splice()`.

```js
function DeleteButton(){
 const dltinpt = Deleteinput.value();

 const index = secretPasswords.indexOf(dlinpt);
 if (index > -1) {
  secretPasswords.splice(index, 1);

 }

}
```

Comment: What do you have an inside secret password? Please send it (of course not the real password)
Maybe this is a scope problome

Comment: Sorry for late responding you question..```const secretPasswords = ["example1","Example2"];```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes made to a value stored in a variable will not be persisted between page loads. That's just a fundamental principle of JavaScript and web browsers. If you want to preserve state between page loads you are going to need to use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: If you want the state to be more ephemeral but also shareable, you could also update the location with state in the URL fragment and then retrieve state from the URL fragment on page load. However this may not work in scenarios where your sketch is being hosted in an iframe.

Comment: Oh, and since you tagged your question as p5.js related even through there is no visible p5.js code, there is some p5.js support for localStorage: https://p5js.org/reference/#group-Data